# how to pass props to component after click on sibling component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I'm a newby to react. On a click of a button, a student is selected (this part works). I want to pass that name to a child component 'bigProfile', but I can't get it to work.

I'm working on this branch: https://github.com/smilingkite/REACT-Evaluation-Tool-for-Teachers/tree/button

Thanks to answer by @Jayabalaji J I now have an app component as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BigProfile from './components/bigProfile';
import fetchStudents from './actions/fetch';
import BigButton from './components/bigButton';
import ProfileListContainer from './components/profileListContainer';

export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            studentName: ''
        };
    }

    pickStudent(array) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        var student = array[index];
        var studentName = student.name;
        this.setState({ studentName: student.name });
        console.log(studentName);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchStudents();
    }

    render() {
        const { students } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <BigProfile name={this.state.studentName} />
                <BigButton
                    onClick={() =>
                        this.pickStudent(selectStudentGroup(students, pickColor()))}
                />
                <ProfileListContainer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        students: store.students
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStudents })(App);
```

The big profile component is as follows:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class BigProfile extends PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        name: '...'
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.name !== nextProps.name) {
            this.setState((this.props.name: nextProps.name));
        }
    }
    render() {
        console.log('this.props (in render): ', this.props.name);
        return (
            <h1>
                {'Ask a question of: '}
                {this.props.name}
            </h1>
        );
    }
}
export default BigProfile;
```

I now get the following error, once I click on the bigButton: "setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables." It refers to this line in BigProfile:

```
this.setState((this.props.name: nextProps.name));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change props to state here

Use this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BigProfile from './components/bigProfile';
import fetchStudents from './actions/fetch';
import BigButton from './components/bigButton';
import ProfileListContainer from './components/profileListContainer';

export class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          studentName: '' //You can set the initial student Name as you wish
        }
        this.pickStudent = this.pickStudent.bind(this);
    }

    pickStudent(array) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        var student = array[index];
        var studentName = student.name;
        this.setState({ studentName: student.name });
        console.log(studentName);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchStudents();
    }

    render() {
        const { students } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <BigProfile name={this.props.studentName} />
                <BigButton
                    onClick={() =>
                        this.pickStudent(selectStudentGroup(students, pickColor()))}
                />
                <ProfileListContainer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        students: store.students
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStudents })(App);
```

Comment: That breaks the app. The message in the browser is : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'studentName' of null "

Comment: sorry i missed the initial part..you need to initialize the state..wait i will update the answer

Comment: I assume you mean to keep '<BigProfile name={this.state.studentName} />' as in your original answer (I tried both).

However, I now get 'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.' after I click on the button In 'BigProfile'. Since it's no longer props, I assume the component also needs to be updated.

Comment: can u update your latest code here..that would be helpful :-)

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your suggestions. I guess the next step is the bigprofile component.

Comment: Simplifying my bigProfile component fixed it, after your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: In this line: this.setState((this.props.name: nextProps.name));  - Syntax is not correct.  It should be,                                                                                 this.setState ({ [yourStateName]: stateValue }).  You should use square brackets to give dynamic state name

Comment: Thanks. I will take that into account in future. However, for this use case it turns out I don't need componentWillMount at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158577/discussion-between-jayabalaji-j-and-katinka-hesselink).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jayabalaji J 's answer, I only needed to simplify my bigProfile component as follows:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'; 
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class BigProfile extends PureComponent {    
static propTypes = {        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired   };

render() {      
return (            <h1>
    {'Ask a question of: '}
    {this.props.name}           </h1>       );  } } 

export default BigProfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BigProfile from './components/bigProfile';
import fetchStudents from './actions/fetch';
import BigButton from './components/bigButton';
import ProfileListContainer from './components/profileListContainer';

export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            studentName: ''
        };
    }

    pickStudent(array) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
        var student = array[index];
        var studentName = student.name;
        this.setState({ studentName: student.name });
        this['studentName'] = studentName;
        console.log(studentName);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchStudents();
    }

    render() {
        const { students } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <BigProfile name={this['studentName']} />
                <BigButton
                    onClick={() =>
                        this.pickStudent(selectStudentGroup(students, pickColor()))}
                />
                <ProfileListContainer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return {
        students: store.students
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStudents })(App);
```

Comment: That gives me the error: "setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables."

Comment: I copy your original code and  add "this['studentName'] = studentName" to the function of pickStudent and  change "<BigProfile name={this.state.studentName} />" to " <BigProfile name={this['studentName']} />"  in the render function.